# Rails dynamic assets Timeout error: ::Sprockets::Railtie.build_environment(Rails.application).find_asset("#{params[:controller]}.css")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-sprockets

Im getting timeout errors while loading assets dynamically.

```
ERROR:
FATAL -- : Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutException (Request ran for longer than 15000ms):
```

Code snippet to load assets dynamically(application.html.erb):

```
stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] if (Rails.application.assets || ::Sprockets::Railtie.build_environment(Rails.application)).find_asset("#{params[:controller]}.css")
= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] if (Rails.application.assets || ::Sprockets::Railtie.build_environment(Rails.application)).find_asset("#{params[:controller]}.js")
```

could you please suggest what can be done to fix the timeout error.

Answer (score 1):

I fix this issue by removing in your **Gemfile:** `gem 'rack-timeout'`
after that, run `bundle` to uninstall it, and then restart the server by running the `rails s`.

I'm waiting that this suggestion is helpful for you.